# Sending string as Uint8 buffer

Tags: javascript, c, arduino, buffer, uint8t

I'm developing a mobile app to communicate with Bluetooth Module. I'm sending data through android app & receiving it on BLE module.

I'm using cordova & BLE central plugin for cordova to communicate with the device from android.

App seems to work fine but there is something wrong with Uint8 buffer.

**ON THE APP PART :**

I'm trying to send string as follow :

```
var data : 'action/523';
```

I'm using following function to convert string to array buffer before I finally send data to BLE device

```
function stringToArrayBuffer(str) {
    // assuming 8 bit bytes
    var ret = new Uint8Array(str.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return ret.buffer;
}

var data = stringToArrayBuffer(data);
ble.writeWithoutResponse(app.connectedPeripheral.id, SERVICE_UUID, WRITE_UUID, data, success, failure);
```

**ON THE DEVICE PART :**

I'm using a simple device specific function to receive data on the BLE device as follow

```
void SimbleeBLE_onReceive(char *data, int len) {
     Serial.print(data); //prints 'action/523';
}
```

Now this works fine but later when I send string as follow

```
var data : 'action/3';
```

It just replaces first digit of the integer & append previous integer value 3[23]  `'action/323/';`

It happens every time I try to send 2 or more digit value first followed by lesser digit value later

Why so ? Is there anything such as buffer cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your devide part, it looks like you are receiving 2 datas:

1. Raw data (char* **non NULL terminated**)
2. Length of the data

You should NULL terminate your received string

```
void SimbleeBLE_onReceive(char *data, int len)
{       
    char tmp[256]={0};
    strncpy(tmp,data,min(len,sizeof(tmp)-1));
    Serial.print(tmp);
}
```

This way, on your second call, you should see **action/3** instead of **action/323/**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation & answer ! Just one error.. There is a missing bracket on line : 4 of the code. :) Please edit. Thanks